# Why can std::function bind functions of different types?

Tags: c++, stdbind

I saw a special usage about `std::bind()`, just like the following code:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        _state_function_map[0] = std::bind(&Test::state_function, _1, _2);
    }
    void test_function() {
        auto it = _state_function_map.find(0);
        int result = it->second(this, 0.0);
    }
private:
    int state_function(const double value) const {
        // do someting
    }
private:
    using func_type = std::function<int(Test* const, const double)>;
    std::unordered_map<int, func_type> _state_function_map;
};
```

What I can't understand is, `func_type` and `Test::state_function` are not the same type, func_type has two parameters, and Test::state_function only has one parameter, so why can they bind `Test::state_function` in `_state_function_map`?

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without knowing what you already know. Do you know what `std::function` is, why it is needed, how it is different from say a function pointer etc?

Comment: `std::bind` is unnecessary, you can insert `&Test::state_function` directly.

Comment: you can write a functor that encapsulates a member function pointer and has an operator `()` that when called uses the `Test*` passed to its operator `()` to call the member function. Thats what `std::function` is in a nutshell, and much more

Comment: why not? Please try to be more specific about what you do not understand

Comment: func_type has two parameters, and Test::state_function only has one parameter，I can't understand how it works.

Comment: Part of the confusion might be because you're mixing `std::bind` and `std::function`. The `std::bind` clearly states that it creates a function with two arguments, `_1` and `_2`. That matches the number expected by `std::function<int(Test* const, const double)>`. The surprise really is that you can use `_2` when binding `&Test::state_function`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How std::bind works with member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636373/how-stdbind-works-with-member-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `func_type` has two parameters, and `Test::state_function` only has one parameter，I can't understand how it works.

For binding purposes, the non-static member function `state_function` has an additional first **implicit object parameter** of type `const Test&`.

Now, when we define a `std::function` object, we specify the *function type* that is the signature of the callable object that object can represent. **When the callable is a member function**, the signature’s first parameter represent the (normally implicit) object on which the member function will be called on. Now, there are two ways to specify the signature in case of a member function:

##### Method 1

Here we say that the object on which the member function will be called will be passed as a pointer.

```
//----------------------------------vvvvv-------------------------->pointer here means a pointer to the object of type `Test` will be passed
using func_type = std::function<int(Test* const, const double)>;
```

This method 1 is what you used in your example. It means that the member function was being  called using a pointer to an object of type `Test`.

##### Method 2

But there is another way of passing the object. In particular, you can sepcify that the object will be passed as a reference as shown below:

```
//----------------------------------------vvvvv------------------>note the reference here which says that here an object of type `Test` will be passed instead of a pointer 
using func_type = std::function<int(const Test&, const double)>;
```

Note also that for the above to work you will have to modify `it->second(this, 0.0);` to

```
//---------vvvvv-------------->note the * used here to dereference 
it->second(*this, 0.0);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/91kysQTYF)

Comment: "For the purposes of overload resolution" - there's no overload resolution here. I know where the quote comes from: for purposes of overload resolution, even **static** functions have an implicit argument. But for **binding purposes**, only non-static members have such an implicit parameter.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, for overload resolution purposes both static and non-static member functions have implicit object parameter as i quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72486959/12002570). I have updated my answer to say for binding purpose instead of overload resolution.